# Recursive Algorithm C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, binary-tree

I need some help with an algorithm using C#.
I have a list of objects, with items multiples of 4, and I should return only the two best items.
Each item has a value and a description. I must also make comparisons to every two elements. And I would like to call this method recursively until I have only 2 elements.

Example:

```
CardList.Add(new Card("Name A", 150));
CardList.Add(new Card("Name B", 100));
CardList.Add(new Card("Name C", 50));
CardList.Add(new Card("Name D", 556));
CardList.Add(new Card("Name E", 170));
CardList.Add(new Card("Name F", 160));
CardList.Add(new Card("Name G", 30));
CardList.Add(new Card("Name H", 650));


public Lis<Card> BestCards(Lis<Card> list){
    List<Card> listResult = new List<Card>(); 
    for(int i=1; i<=list.lenght; i+2)
    {
        if(list[i].value> list[i+1].value)
            listResult.Add(list[i])
        else if (list[i].value< list[i+1].value)
            listResult.Add(list[i+1])
        else if (list[i].value==list[i+1].value)    
        {
            // first element according to alphabetical order of the description
            listResult.Add(???)
        }   
    return listResult;
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: If you just want the two best items why don't you sort the list and return the first two items? What's different about what you want that isn't that? There are more efficient ways to find the top K elements but they are harder to implement.

Comment: Does "I must also make comparisons to every two elements" mean that you need to compare _every_ possible pair of items? What is _best_? Do you have code that compiles, i.e. doesn't have `list.lenght`?

Comment: Is this a homework question? I'd like to fix this code but if it's homework that would be counterproductive...

Comment: Why does this need to be recursive?

Comment: Usually you do not use recursion on two level compares because it is simpler to just use two nested for loops.  Recursion reduces the number of lines of code and becomes efficient when you need three of more nested for loops to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using the method that you are currently using, you could be losing data, since you are getting rid of an item every time you do a comparison, without checking if it is better than the whole list.

I would suggest sorting the list, and then taking the top two items that way, or you can compare one item to every other item, and find the best two.

Answer (score 0):

This solution should meet your requirements.

The first method iterates while there are more than 2 cards remaining, the second method compares the cards and returns the resulting list:

```
public List<Card> BestCards(List<Card> list){
    List<Card> listResult = list; 

    while (listResult.Count > 2)
        listResult = ReduceList(listResult);

    return listResult;
}


public List<Card> ReduceList(List<Card> list)
{
    var listResult = new List<Card>(); 

    for(int i = 0; i <= list.Count - 1; i+=2)
    {
        if(list[i].value > list[i+1].value)
            listResult.Add(list[i]);
        else if (list[i].value< list[i+1].value)
            listResult.Add(list[i+1]);
        else if (list[i].value==list[i+1].value)
            listResult.Add(list[i].name.CompareTo(list[i+1].name) <= 0 ? list[i] : list[i+1]);
    }

    return listResult;
}
```